# Python server configuration

Tags: python, server

Please help me with python server configuration. I am getting an error when I execute .pyw file in cmd with python command I got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ff.pyw", line 2, in <module>
import cx_Oracle
ImportError:DLL load failed: %1 is not  a valid Win32 application.

(Dependency walker in cx_oracle.pyd found several errors: oci.dll is 64-bit,at least one requred implicit or forwarded dependency was not found.
```

At least one module has an uresolved import due to a missing export in an implicitly dependent module.
Modules with different CPU types were found.
    API-ms-win-service-private-L1-1-1.dll error opening file and etc.)
    I replaced 64-bit oci.dll to 32-bit in
    C:\app\client\user\product\12.1.0\client_1\ folder.
    (actually i can't figure out why in 32-bit cx_oracle.pyd  oci.dll was 64-bit.)
Then error was:
    import pyodbc
    ImportError: No module named pyodbc.
    After installing pyodbc, error was: IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
    (Permission denied to ff.log file).
After changing folder pirmissions to executable where my .pyw files located,
another error occurred:

```
con_qm = cx_Oracle.connect(..,.., dsn_tns)
InterfaceError: Unable to acquire Oracle environment handle.
```

I'm an administrator. My OS: win server 2012r2 64-bit, python 2.7.9 (anaconda 2.2.0 32-bit),python 2.7 cx_oracle-5.1.2-10g 32-bit,ora client 12.1.0 32-bit.
Paths:
    C:\app\client\user\product\12.1.0\client_1;
    C:\app\client\user\product\12.1.0\client_1\bin;
    %SystemRoot%\system32;
    %SystemRoot%;
    %SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;
    %SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
    C:\Anaconda;
    C:\Anaconda\Scripts
    C:\app\client\user\product\12.1.0\client_1\Network\Admin.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: People, help me with my problem please please!

Comment: thanks to all, my problem has been resolved.